# AD Domain: Deploy Thunderbird Gmail Settings

Tags: active-directory, deployment, thunderbird, windows-10

In our (small) organization, we are using Google Apps (aka Gmail for business) as an email service. We found Thunderbird to be a good client for Google Apps and wish to keep using it.

Now, we are about to install new Windows 10 computers. They will have Thunderbird pre-installed but not set up. Our users are really not very tech savvy so I would like to make this as easy as possible on them.

The goal is that the user can just sit at his computer, open Thunderbird and all he will be asked is his email address and his password, or even better just his password, all other information should be already present. Furthermore, the profile should be network based so that he can easily switch to another computer without having to do it again.

*How would you achieve that in the most efficient way?*

I found some information on the web on how to provide mail server information to the users using autoconfig but that just doesn't go far enough for me.

Some additional information:

- IMAP/SMTP-Server address is, naturally, the same for all users
- The same credentials are used for email retrieval (IMAP) as well as transmission (SMTP)
- Email Addresses all have the same pattern, firstname.lastname@company.com.
- First and Last Names are stored in the Active Directory. (That's really just a bonus; I am fine to enter the addresses manually).